# Importing pages breaks category feature

Tags: mediawiki

I just installed MediaWiki 1.27.1 and setup completes without issue on a server with Ubuntu 16.04, nginx, PHP 5.6, and MariaDB 10.1.

I created an export file with a different wiki using the Special:Export page. I then imported the articles to the new wiki using the Special:Import page. The file size is smaller than any limits and time the operation takes to complete is much less than configured timeouts.

Before import, I have created articles and categories and everything works as expected.

However, after importing, when I create a category tag on an article, clicking the link to the category's page doesn't show the article in the category.

I am using this markup within the article to create the category:

```
[[Category:Category Name]]
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `php maintenance/RunJobs.php` — usually you shouldn't need to, but after an import there may be lots of pending jobs (they usually get run one per request; see [$wgJobRunRate](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgJobRunRate)).

Comment: Thanks. I can't confirm this fixes the problem right now, but when I have my test server back up I will return and confirm.